# Movie about a former bounty hunter who is threatened by his previous employers

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama, action

In this film from ~10 years ago, an ordinary guy works as a bartender in a diner. One day the diner gets raided by some robbers and our bartender neutralize them professionally.

This accident gets him on to the news and shortly after the mafia arrive at his home. We discover that he is a retired bounty hunter who broke with his past and started a new life in a small distant town, married, and had kids.

The mafia pursue him to get him to return to the business and threaten his family. At the end, he raids the main boss's house and kills him; then his family forgives him and takes him back.

There is one intimate scene in the movie there main hero and his wife have a romantic time when she surprises him by dressing as a cheerleader.

In the final scene he enters his home (after killing the boss) and the family is having dinner. His little daughter stands up, goes to the kitchen's counter-top and fetches him a plate.

Comment: A cheerleader you say? [Mercy](https://youtu.be/YAjR4SniykY?t=6s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like [A History of Violence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_History_of_Violence), starring Viggo Mortensen:

> The film stars Viggo Mortensen as the owner of a small-town diner who
>   is thrust into the spotlight after confronting two robbers in
>   self-defense, thus changing his life forever.

[image]

Supporting evidence from the wiki:

> He is visited by scarred gangster Carl Fogarty (Ed Harris), who
>   alleges that ***Tom is actually a gangster*** named Joey Cusack who had
>   dealings with him in the Irish Mob in Philadelphia some years ago.

Also, at the end:

> Tom returns home, where the atmosphere is tense and silent as the
>   family sits around the dinner table. The future of his marriage and
>   his life as Tom Stall is uncertain, but ***Jack and Sarah indicate their
>   acceptance of their father by setting a plate for him and passing him
>   some food.*** The film ends as Eddie looks up at Tom, leaving their future
>   in question.

Cheerleader scene can also be [found on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mario%20bello%20cheerleader%20scene).